# How to set pagination in laravel 5 while passing an array from the controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

Here is my code

**Controller**

```
$query = "SELECT `h`.*,".$countquery.",".$minquery." FROM `abserve_hotels` as `h`";
$aReslts = $this->model->getData($query,$sqlCond);

$this->data['Rooms'] =!empty($aReslts) ? $aReslts : '';

return view('hotel.list', $this->data);
```

Here,`$sqlCond` returns several result set while passing Ajax and for post action

**View**

```
<?php
if(($Rooms)){
?>
@foreach($Rooms as $room)
{{ $room->id }}
@endforeach

<?php
}
?>
```

I tried several ways to set the pagination methods..But it din't work for me..

How should I make pagination for this..Could someone help me!!..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can create a paginator manually by using

`$pagination = Paginator::make($this->data['Rooms'], count($this->data['Rooms']), 5);`

To display links use `echo $pagination->links();`
Or `{{ $pagination->links() }}`

Answer (score 2):

Use this way .... very easy

```
public function items(Request $request)
{
    $items = [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3',
        'item4',
        'item5',
        'item6',
        'item7',
        'item8',
        'item9',
        'item10'
        ];

    // Get current page form url e.x. &page=1
    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    // Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
    $itemCollection = collect($items);

    // Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
    $perPage = 1;

    // Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage, $perPage)->all();

    // Create our paginator and pass it to the view
    $paginatedItems= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $perPage);

    // set url path for generated links
    $paginatedItems->setPath($request->url());

    return view('items_view', ['items' => $paginatedItems]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me!! Also in blade file I added {{ $paginatedItems->links() }} to display pagination Links.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function controllerFunction($page=1)
{
   $limit = 10;
   $start = ($page-1)*$limit;
   $query = "SELECT `h`.*,".$countquery.",".$minquery." FROM `abserve_hotels` as `h`";
$aReslts = $this->model->getData($query,$sqlCond)->skip($start)->take($limit);

$this->data['Rooms'] =!empty($aReslts) ? $aReslts : '';

return view('hotel.list', $this->data);
}
```

This will give you paginated content. You can add pagination on your view via laravel pagination or using a custom code.

Comment: Using this code in controller and adding ` echo $aHotelRooms->render(); ` in view may set pagination!!...

Comment: And in my controller function I already pass a `Request $request` how should I give the `$page=1` by using `,` !!...

Comment: When use `echo $Rooms->render()` I'm always getting `1 FatalErrorException in 3d4c6f287876462533e51d881f81767c line 45: Call to a member function render() on array` what should I do for it.. : (